# How to get the relative mouse movement with pyqt5

Tags: python, python-3.x, qt5, pyqt5

Here is my simplified widget. I want to:

- hide the mouse
- lock it to the center of the window
- get the relative mouse movement

I want similar mouse control to first person shooters.

```
class QGLControllerWidget(QtOpenGL.QGLWidget):
    def __init__(self, app):
        fmt = QtOpenGL.QGLFormat()
        fmt.setVersion(3, 3)
        fmt.setProfile(QtOpenGL.QGLFormat.CoreProfile)
        fmt.setSampleBuffers(True)
        fmt.setDepthBufferSize(24)

        super(QGLControllerWidget, self).__init__(fmt, None)

        self.setMouseTracking(True)

def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
    print(event.x(), event.y())
```